# JSON Encoding - Get MySQL data to an iPhone

Tags: php, mysql, json

Im new to JSON and have whats probably a basic question.  I have some MySQL rows I want grab with Php, and then JSON encode for a response to an iphone request.

so the questions are:

1) Whats the format for the array to encode this info?

2) Where the does the response code (200) fit into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tutorial. http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Basically on the PHP side, write a script that fetches the MySQL data and then echo back the output of json_encode. The iPhone side will call to the URL of this script using the method above.

I would suggest you take a look at json.org and familiarize yourself with the JSON format.

Comment: hey guys, im actually looking for the format of the array that I would return to the iphone from php.  Will check out json.org though

Answer (score 0):

1) On the Obj-c side of things, have you heard of Stig's JSON framework? https://github.com/stig/json-framework

I use it in my iPhone apps and it works very well for encoding and decoding JSON. Are you interested in the the format for the array to encode the information on the iPhone side or server side? You should create the array in the way that makes the most sense and then make sure the iPhone side is reading the array the same way the PHP side sends it.

2) The HTTP 200 response code simply means your request has succeeded. As opposed to like a 404 or something where the webpage doesn't exist.

Comment: hey guys, im actually looking for the format of the array that I would return to the iphone from php

Comment: You could return anything from PHP. Then on the iPhone side you take care of the parsing/creating for the array.